# LogisticRegression penalty set l1 or l2 is equal to use Lasso or Ridge？

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

`from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression`
I want to know if using `LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')` equal to use `Lasso()`?
or `LogisticRegression(penalty='l2')` equal to use `Ridge()`?
I know if use Lasso alpha=1.0, if use LogisticRegression() C=1.0,but What a difference?
In addtion,when the question is a binary classification,I should use which of them?
Multi-classification? regression?
PS:I'm not very good at English,sry.

I know if use Lasso alpha=1.0, if use LogisticRegression() C=1.0.

Comment: I am not certain your question is clear.  Is it "what is the difference between: Lasso, Ridge, and Logistic Regression" or "what is the difference between L1 abnd L2 regularization" or "Why is the parameter called Alpha in some algorithms and C in others, is there a difference?"

Answer (score 0):

My understanding (still very much a noob) is that Ridge ("[Linear least squares with l2 regularization](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html)" and Lasso ("[Linear Model trained with L1 prior as regularizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html)") regression are "true" regression algorithms and that Logisitic Regression (in spite of its name) is more of a classification ("[Logistic Regression (aka logit, MaxEnt) classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)") algorithm.  According to the SciKit documentation, either L1, L2, or both regularization can be applied.

L1 and L2 are different types of regularlization.  [L2 adds the "squared magnitude" while L1 adds the "Absolute value of the magnitude"](https://towardsdatascience.com/l1-and-l2-regularization-methods-ce25e7fc831c).

C and ALpha are related hyperparameters, but different.  According to scikit documentation:

> Cfloat, default=1.0
> Inverse of regularization strength; must be a positive float. Like in support vector machines, smaller values specify stronger regularization.

If you are looking to understand the role of the C parameter maybe check these out:

- [What is C parameter in sklearn Logistic Regression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67513075/what-is-c-parameter-in-sklearn-logistic-regression)
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508984/why-regularization-parameter-called-as-lambda-in-theory-and-alpha-in-python

Lastly if you use

- Alpha == 1 -> C == 1.0
- Alpha == 10 -> C == 0.1
- Alpha == 100 -> C == 0.01